# Tables: how to control left and right cell margins?

Tags: tables, margins

Despite searching the forum, I still can't figure out how to control the internal cell left and right margins. In the example below, how can I tweak (e.g. reduce) the left margin for the "L-text" cells, and the right margin for the "R-text" ones? Note that defining the column widths is required. Thanks, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex

\newlength{\ColWidthNormal}         \setlength{\ColWidthNormal}{1.50cm}
\newlength{\ColWidthRowHeader}      \setlength{\ColWidthRowHeader}{1.50cm}

\newlength{\RuleOffsetLeft} \setlength{\RuleOffsetLeft}{-0.4pt}
\newlength{\RuleThicknessNormal} \setlength{\RuleThicknessNormal}{1.0pt}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\leavevmode}p{\ColWidthNormal}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\ColWidthNormal}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\ColWidthRowHeader}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    |L|R|R|
}
\cmidrule[\RuleThicknessNormal](l{\RuleOffsetLeft}){2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C-text}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C-text} \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
L-text& R-text& R-text \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
L-text& R-text& R-text \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Update: the solution with `\hspace` doesn't work below a minimum column width! Any  ideas on how to solve this?

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex

\newlength{\ColWidthNormal}         \setlength{\ColWidthNormal}{1.50cm}
%\newlength{\ColWidthRowHeader}         \setlength{\ColWidthRowHeader}{1.50cm}
\newlength{\ColWidthRowHeader}      \setlength{\ColWidthRowHeader}{1.00cm}

\newlength{\RuleOffsetLeft} \setlength{\RuleOffsetLeft}{-0.4pt}
\newlength{\RuleThicknessNormal} \setlength{\RuleThicknessNormal}{1.0pt}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\leavevmode}p{\ColWidthNormal}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\ColWidthNormal}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\ColWidthRowHeader}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{
    |@{\hspace{0pt}}L|
    R@{\hspace{-3pt}}|
    R@{\hspace{-12pt}}|
}
\cmidrule[\RuleThicknessNormal](l{\RuleOffsetLeft}){2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{My C-text}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{My C-text} \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
L-text& R-text& R-text \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
L-text& R-text& R-text \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `@{\hspace{some length}}`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex

\newlength{\ColWidthNormal} \setlength{\ColWidthNormal}{1.50cm}
\newlength{\ColWidthRowHeader} \setlength{\ColWidthRowHeader}{1.50cm}

\newlength{\RuleOffsetLeft} \setlength{\RuleOffsetLeft}{-0.4pt}
\newlength{\RuleThicknessNormal} \setlength{\RuleThicknessNormal}{1.0pt}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\leavevmode}p{\ColWidthNormal}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\ColWidthNormal}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\ColWidthRowHeader}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{%
    |@{\hspace{0pt}}L|R@{\hspace{1pt}}|R@{\hspace{2pt}}|
}
\cmidrule[\RuleThicknessNormal](l{\RuleOffsetLeft}){2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C-text}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C-text} \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
L-text& R-text& R-text \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
L-text& R-text& R-text \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessNormal]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Bernard; this is both simple and effective! :)

Comment: Bernard, for some reason the hack breaks if I reduce the column widths (see updated example)... any suggestions? :(

Comment: It seems to happen because the cells aren't wide enough for the chosen margin + the default margin on the other side (6pt). If you still reduce the width, it breaks into two lines and every is aligned as wanted. You can reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{some length}` if necessary.

Comment: The problem with `\tabcolsep` is that it affects the other cells, so I cannot reduce it arbitrarily without affecting the whole table. In the updated example, I've reduced it to 3pt, and the `\hspace` is still unable to enforce the desired right margin :(

Comment: The cell width and the cell content width are in a sort of grey zone, and I'm afraid with so small widths, each case will be a particular case and you have to do things by hand. You may, for instance, add a `@{}` on the left side of the problematic cell.